# Cross Domain Iframe AJAX Hash History IE6/7

Tags: ajax, cross-domain, browser-history

We are using document.domain to sort out our cross domain stuff. Recently I decided to start working on a hash system on our website so there is history in the browser and bookmark links etc.

After some time google'ing I found [reallysimplehistory](http://code.google.com/p/reallysimplehistory/) and decided to give it a try. It works outstanding in IE8 and Chrome etc. I run into my problem in IE6 and 7 where it needs to use an IFrame to simulate history changes.

When I hit the back button in the browser it "goes back" a page but it never changes the hash in the url like it should. It has the correct number of history pages and it changes the hash when I add a new hash, but the backward and forward buttons of the browser aren't changing it.

Using the demo they supplied it was working just fine in IE6/7. When I introduced document.domain to the demo it stopped working and gave the same results my website gave.

So what do I need to do to get the back/forward buttons working in the browser again?

Answer (score 0):

It might not be what you're looking for but I'd at least recommend looking at [jquery-bbq](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) which is a back functionality jquery plugin. You might be able to steal something from the source or base your app on it.

Comment: we use prototype as our main library and would rather not add on a whole new library. I can certainly look at the source though and see if it is of any use.